# How to access table which has its one to one relations?

Tags: django, database, django-models

Sorry, I don't know what should be the title for this question. But here is my question.

In Django we User table comes as default.

Now I have another table User_Info which has User id as (one-to-one/foreign key), 
I don't know what to take one-to-one or foreignkey.

Now I want to access this User_Info table which has enrollment through the User table in HTML. (Is it possible?)

example:-

```
class User_info(models.Model):
    mobileNo = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)
    User_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

we have User class as default and has primary key, username, email.

```
<h1> Name {{ user.username }} </h1> <!-- we can have username stored in -->
<h1> mobileNo {{ user.(i need help here, what to write)</h1> <!-- from user how to get mobile number-->
```

If I am missing anything else please ask.
Thank you:)

I forget to mention that the user has already been logged in so I can have the user table access in HTML.
Also 1 user has only 1 mobile number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your Model class to be according to [Django coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style)

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    mobile_number = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

One-to-one relationship [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

```
user.user_info.mobile_number
```